# SGE unknown resource "nodes"

Tags: sungridengine

I submit a job on SGE with parameter -l like:

```
qsub -pe orte 4 -l nodes=4 run.sh
```

However, the system displays that:

```
Unable to run job: unknown resource "nodes".
```

Could you tell me why and how to solve it?
Thank you very much!

Comment: What is your intent with that parameter?

Comment: I want to request 4 nodes to run my job. My job was programed with MPI. I think there is not nodes resource in the SGE cluster.

Answer (score 2):

With Sun Grid Engine, the correct resource parameter is `h`, not `nodes`:

```
echo 'echo `hostname`' | qsub -l h=<some_hostname>
```

Using this example, you should see the hostname you specified in the standard output file.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a nodes resource.  Instead you request a parallel environment and a number of slots (map to cores usually).  The number of nodes you get is determined by the alloaction_rule of the parallel environment.  There is usually a simple pe called something like mpi that will pack as many slots(cores) onto each node as will fit.   Some people have created configs for grid engine that let it have a more PBS like  syntax.