# SGE faild to submit job, attribute is not a memory value

Tags: qsub, sungridengine

I failed to submit a job with mem attribute. Since I am novice and after google two days, I look for help here. Any suggestion would be grateful!

Following is what had I done:

\1. Submit my script:

```
qsub -S /bin/bash -A assembly -pe threads 16 -l mem=2GB -cwd -N "pBcR_correct_asm" -j y -o /dev/null runCorrection.sh

Unable to run job: unknown resource "mem".
Exiting.
```

\2. Considering that I had replace "h" to "host", which solve my problem according to [SGE unknown resource "nodes"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27754174/sge-unknown-resource-nodes), I replace "m" to "mem”， and it didn't work.

\3. After google, I know "h" is the shortcut that was defined in "/opt/gridengine/util/resources/centry/
hostname", and can be confirmed with "qconf -sc":

```
qconf -sc

#name               shortcut   type        relop requestable consumable default  urgency 
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
arch                a          RESTRING    ==    YES         NO         NONE     0
calendar            c          RESTRING    ==    YES         NO         NONE     0
cpu                 cpu        DOUBLE      >=    YES         NO         0        0
display_win_gui     dwg        BOOL        ==    YES         NO         0        0
h_core              h_core     MEMORY      <=    YES         NO         0        0
h_cpu               h_cpu      TIME        <=    YES         NO         0:0:0    0
h_data              h_data     MEMORY      <=    YES         NO         0        0
h_fsize             h_fsize    MEMORY      <=    YES         NO         0        0
h_rss               h_rss      MEMORY      <=    YES         NO         0        0
h_rt                h_rt       TIME        <=    YES         NO         0:0:0    0
h_stack             h_stack    MEMORY      <=    YES         NO         0        0
h_vmem              h_vmem     MEMORY      <=    YES         NO         0        0
hostname            h          HOST        ==    YES         NO         NONE     0
load_avg            la         DOUBLE      >=    NO          NO         0        0
load_long           ll         DOUBLE      >=    NO          NO         0        0
load_medium         lm         DOUBLE      >=    NO          NO         0        0
load_short          ls         DOUBLE      >=    NO          NO         0        0
m_core              core       INT         <=    YES         NO         0        0
m_socket            socket     INT         <=    YES         NO         0        0
m_topology          topo       RESTRING    ==    YES         NO         NONE     0
m_topology_inuse    utopo      RESTRING    ==    YES         NO         NONE     0
mem_free            mf         MEMORY      <=    YES         NO         0        0
mem_total           mt         MEMORY      <=    YES         NO         0        0
mem_used            mu         MEMORY      >=    YES         NO         0        0
```

\4. I thus replaced "mt" to "mem", but it complained attribute problem. According to above output, it seemed the mem_total is almost same as "hostname" that worked previously. Then, I think jsv may be a problem after going through the SGE guide, but I can't find any scripts contain "Unable to run job: attribute......", which under the director of "/opt/gridengine/util/resources/jsv". I think I have to configure some files, but what these files, and what should I do?

```
qsub -S /bin/bash -A assembly -pe threads 16 -l mt=2GB -cwd -N "pBcR_correct_asm" -j y -o test.out  runCorrection.sh

Unable to run job: attribute "mem_total" is not a memory value.
Exiting.
```

Answer (score 1):

@Vince!

Thanks for your reply very much.

Finally I solve my problem, by using "h_vmem=2g" ("2GB" would give error), but I don't know where to find how to design the value of the complex (MEMORY).

Following information is un-necessary now.

I had read the website you gave, and configured the attribute of h_vmem and s_vmeme in complex to "consumable", but it didn't work. I guess I have to configure "complex_value" of queue which is "NONE" at the moment. However, I can't open the web http://gridscheduler.sourceforge.net/htmlman/htmlman5/sge_types.html?pathrev=V62u5_TAG that may tell me how to configure. Am I right to configure to configure queue? Do I have to configure host too?

Any suggestions would be grateful!

Fowllowing is what had I done:

\1. Change the attribute of consumable to "YES" for h_vmem and s_vmem:

```
qconf -sc

#name               shortcut   type        relop requestable consumable default  urgency 
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
arch                a          RESTRING    ==    YES         NO         NONE     0
calendar            c          RESTRING    ==    YES         NO         NONE     0
cpu                 cpu        DOUBLE      >=    YES         NO         0        0
display_win_gui     dwg        BOOL        ==    YES         NO         0        0
h_core              h_core     MEMORY      <=    YES         NO         0        0
h_cpu               h_cpu      TIME        <=    YES         NO         0:0:0    0
h_data              h_data     MEMORY      <=    YES         NO         0        0
h_fsize             h_fsize    MEMORY      <=    YES         NO         0        0
h_rss               h_rss      MEMORY      <=    YES         NO         0        0
h_rt                h_rt       TIME        <=    YES         NO         0:0:0    0
h_stack             h_stack    MEMORY      <=    YES         NO         0        0
h_vmem              h_vmem     MEMORY      <=    YES         YES        0        0
hostname            h          HOST        ==    YES         NO         NONE     0
load_avg            la         DOUBLE      >=    NO          NO         0        0
load_long           ll         DOUBLE      >=    NO          NO         0        0
load_medium         lm         DOUBLE      >=    NO          NO         0        0
load_short          ls         DOUBLE      >=    NO          NO         0        0
m_core              core       INT         <=    YES         NO         0        0
m_socket            socket     INT         <=    YES         NO         0        0
m_topology          topo       RESTRING    ==    YES         NO         NONE     0
m_topology_inuse    utopo      RESTRING    ==    YES         NO         NONE     0
mem_free            mf         MEMORY      <=    YES         NO         0        0
mem_total           mt         MEMORY      <=    YES         NO         0        0
mem_used            mu         MEMORY      >=    YES         NO         0        0
min_cpu_interval    mci        TIME        <=    NO          NO         0:0:0    0
np_load_avg         nla        DOUBLE      >=    NO          NO         0        0
np_load_long        nll        DOUBLE      >=    NO          NO         0        0
np_load_medium      nlm        DOUBLE      >=    NO          NO         0        0
np_load_short       nls        DOUBLE      >=    NO          NO         0        0
num_proc            p          INT         ==    YES         NO         0        0
qname               q          RESTRING    ==    YES         NO         NONE     0
rerun               re         BOOL        ==    NO          NO         0        0
s_core              s_core     MEMORY      <=    YES         NO         0        0
s_cpu               s_cpu      TIME        <=    YES         NO         0:0:0    0
s_data              s_data     MEMORY      <=    YES         NO         0        0
s_fsize             s_fsize    MEMORY      <=    YES         NO         0        0
s_rss               s_rss      MEMORY      <=    YES         NO         0        0
s_rt                s_rt       TIME        <=    YES         NO         0:0:0    0
s_stack             s_stack    MEMORY      <=    YES         NO         0        0
s_vmem              s_vmem     MEMORY      <=    YES         YES        0        0
seq_no              seq        INT         ==    NO          NO         0        0
slots               s          INT         <=    YES         YES        1        1000
swap_free           sf         MEMORY      <=    YES         NO         0        0
swap_rate           sr         MEMORY      >=    YES         NO         0        0
swap_rsvd           srsv       MEMORY      >=    YES         NO         0        0
swap_total          st         MEMORY      <=    YES         NO         0        0
swap_used           su         MEMORY      >=    YES         NO         0        0
tmpdir              tmp        RESTRING    ==    NO          NO         NONE     0
virtual_free        vf         MEMORY      <=    YES         NO         0        0
virtual_total       vt         MEMORY      <=    YES         NO         0        0
virtual_used        vu         MEMORY      >=    YES         NO         0        0
# >#< starts a comment but comments are not saved across edits --------
```

\2. Submit my job to the queue of smp.q, and it complained the same problem:

```
qsub -S /bin/bash -A assembly -q smp.q -pe newPe 16 -l h_vmem=2GB -cwd -N "pBcR_correct_asm" -j y -o runCorrection.sh

Unable to run job: attribute "h_vmem" is not a memory value.
Exiting.
```

\3. The information of smp.q. I think "complex_values" should be changed and "h_vmem" can keep unchanged:

```
qconf -sq smp.q

qname                 smp.q
hostlist              @smp.q
seq_no                0
load_thresholds       np_load_avg=1.75
suspend_thresholds    NONE
nsuspend              1
suspend_interval      00:05:00
priority              0
min_cpu_interval      00:05:00
processors            UNDEFINED
qtype                 BATCH INTERACTIVE
ckpt_list             NONE
pe_list               make newPe
rerun                 FALSE
slots                 160
tmpdir                /tmp
shell                 /bin/csh
prolog                NONE
epilog                NONE
shell_start_mode      posix_compliant
starter_method        NONE
suspend_method        NONE
resume_method         NONE
terminate_method      NONE
notify                00:00:60
owner_list            NONE
user_lists            NONE
xuser_lists           NONE
subordinate_list      NONE
complex_values        NONE
projects              NONE
xprojects             NONE
calendar              NONE
initial_state         default
s_rt                  INFINITY
h_rt                  INFINITY
s_cpu                 INFINITY
h_cpu                 INFINITY
s_fsize               INFINITY
h_fsize               INFINITY
s_data                INFINITY
h_data                INFINITY
s_stack               INFINITY
h_stack               INFINITY
s_core                INFINITY
h_core                INFINITY
s_rss                 INFINITY
h_rss                 INFINITY
s_vmem                INFINITY
h_vmem                INFINITY
```

\4. The information of hosts in @smp.q:

```
qconf -sconf smp03.local

#smp03.local:
mailer                       /bin/mail
xterm                        /usr/bin/X11/xterm
execd_spool_dir              /opt/gridengine/default/spool
```

\5. The global information. Have I add h_vmem and s_vmem here?

```
qconf -sconf

#global:
execd_spool_dir              /opt/gridengine/default/spool
mailer                       /bin/mail
xterm                        /usr/bin/X11/xterm
load_sensor                  none
prolog                       none
epilog                       none
shell_start_mode             posix_compliant
login_shells                 sh,ksh,csh,tcsh
min_uid                      0
min_gid                      0
user_lists                   none
xuser_lists                  none
projects                     none
xprojects                    none
enforce_project              false
enforce_user                 auto
load_report_time             00:00:40
max_unheard                  00:05:00
reschedule_unknown           00:00:00
loglevel                     log_warning
administrator_mail           none
set_token_cmd                none
pag_cmd                      none
token_extend_time            none
shepherd_cmd                 none
qmaster_params               none
execd_params                 ENABLE_ADDGRP_KILL=TRUE H_MEMORYLOCKED=infinity
reporting_params             accounting=true reporting=true \
                             flush_time=00:00:15 joblog=true sharelog=00:00:00
finished_jobs                100
gid_range                    20000-20100
qlogin_command               builtin
qlogin_daemon                builtin
rlogin_command               builtin
rlogin_daemon                builtin
rsh_command                  builtin
rsh_daemon                   builtin
max_aj_instances             2000
max_aj_tasks                 75000
max_u_jobs                   0
max_jobs                     0
max_advance_reservations     0
auto_user_oticket            0
auto_user_fshare             0
auto_user_default_project    none
auto_user_delete_time        86400
delegated_file_staging       false
reprioritize                 0
jsv_url                      none
jsv_allowed_mod              ac,h,i,e,o,j,M,N,p,w
```

Comment: I think I know why I failed. It seemed the h_vmem isn't configure global, that is I have to "qconf -mconf global" and add "h_vmem 1024M". But I can't test it as the administrator is out. If it work， I would post solution here.

Answer (score 0):

What you likely want is `h_vmem`. At least that is the attribute I always use to specify the memory I want request for a job.

See:

http://gridscheduler.sourceforge.net/htmlman/htmlman5/queue_conf.html?pathrev=V62u5_TAG

Specifically,

```
     The resource limit parameters s_vmem and h_vmem  are  imple-
     mented  by  Sun  Grid  Engine  as a job limit. They impose a
     limit on the amount of combined virtual memory  consumed  by
     all the processes in the job. If h_vmem is exceeded by a job
     running in the queue, it is aborted  via  a  SIGKILL  signal
     (see  kill(1)).   If  s_vmem  is exceeded, the job is sent a
     SIGXCPU signal which can be caught by the job.  If you  wish
     to  allow  a  job  to  be "warned" so it can exit gracefully
     before it is killed then you should set the s_vmem limit  to
     a  lower  value  than  h_vmem.   For parallel processes, the
     limit is applied per slot which means that the limit is mul-
     tiplied  by the number of slots being used by the job before
     being applied.
```

Also, you may need to set this as consumable using `qconf`.